# Getting Gmail Folders Size and messages count with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Below script does not capture the total count of messages `folderMessageCount` and the Total size of the Folder `folderSize`.
The result I get is `[[[Gmail]/Junk E-mail, 0.0, 0.00 MB, 0.00 GB], [[Gmail]/Sent Items, 0.0, 0.00 MB, 0.00 GB], ....`

I also replaced the code `message.getRawContent().length` with `Utilities.newBlob(message.getRawContent()).getBytes().length` but the result did Not change.

As a non-programmer it took me a while to put this together from different codes, hope someone can help me fix this.

FYI, the end result I want is the results for each Gmail folder by Month (..,Jan-2018,..,Jan-2023, Feb-2023,...), but that's after I get this to work.

```
function getGmailFoldersWithStorageSize() {
  var folders = GmailApp.getUserLabels();
  var foldersWithSize = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
    var folder = folders[i];
    var folderName = folder.getName();
    var folderSize = getFolderStorageSize(folder);
    var folderSizeMB = folderSize / (1024 * 1024); // Convert to MB
    var folderSizeGB = folderSize / (1024 * 1024 * 1024); // Convert to GB
    var folderMessageCount = getFolderMessageCount(folder); // Get message count
    foldersWithSize.push([folderName, folderMessageCount, folderSizeMB.toFixed(2) + " MB", folderSizeGB.toFixed(2) + " GB"]);
  }

  // Log the output to the Apps Script console
  Logger.log(foldersWithSize);

  return foldersWithSize;
}

function getFolderStorageSize(folder) {
  var query = "label:" + folder.getName();
  var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
  var totalSize = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      totalSize += getMessageSizeWithAttachments(messages[j]); // Update to call getMessageSizeWithAttachments()
    }
  }

  return totalSize;
}

function getFolderMessageCount(folder) {
  var query = "label:" + folder.getName();
  var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
  var messageCount = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    messageCount += messages.length;
  }

  return messageCount;
}

function getMessageSizeWithAttachments(message) {
  var messageSize = message.getRawContent().length;
  var attachments = message.getAttachments();

  for (var i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++) {
    messageSize += attachments[i].getSize();
  }

  return messageSize;
}
```